# NavDropdown not set to active when MenuItem child link is active

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap

I am facing this issue that on select of MenuItem child link of react-bootstrap NavDropdown then NavDropdown title is not set to active.

1. My NavDropDown code:

   ```
     <NavDropdown eventKey={4} title="Manage User" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
       <LinkContainer to="/users/add">
         <MenuItem eventKey={4.1}>Add User</MenuItem>
       </LinkContainer>
       <IndexLinkContainer to="/users">
         <MenuItem eventKey={4.2}>View User</MenuItem>
       </IndexLinkContainer>
     </NavDropdown>
   ```
2. Routes

   ```
   <Route path="/users" component={Users}>
     <IndexRoute component={UserList} />
     <Route path="/users/add" component={AddUser} />
     <Route path="/users/:id/edit" component={EditUser} />
   </Route>
   ```

The NavDropDown title 'Manage User' is never set to active even after a MenuItem has been routed and selected.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing similar problem, I solved it like this.

You need to define `activeKey` prop on the `<Nav >`, this value `activeKey` this will decide which link is active.

```
class Navigation extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          activeKey : 0
        }

        this.toggleClass = this.toggleClass.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        if(window.location.pathname === "/users/add") {
          this.setState({ activeKey : 4.1 });
        } else if(window.location.pathname === "/users") {
          this.setState({ activeKey : 4.2 });
        }
    }

    toggleClass(e) {

      if(e.target.pathname === "/users/add") {
        this.setState({ activeKey : 4.1 });
      } else if(e.target.pathname === "/users") {
        this.setState({ activeKey : 4.2 });
      }
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <Navbar inverse fluid collapseOnSelect>
              <Navbar.Collapse>
                <Nav pullRight activeKey={this.state.activeKey}>
                  <NavDropdown eventKey={4} title="Manage User" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                    <LinkContainer to="/users/add" onClick={this.toggleClass}>
                      <MenuItem eventKey={4.1}>Add User</MenuItem>
                    </LinkContainer>
                    <IndexLinkContainer to="/users" onClick={this.toggleClass}>
                      <MenuItem eventKey={4.2}>View User</MenuItem>
                    </IndexLinkContainer>
                  </NavDropdown>
                </Nav>
              </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Navbar>
        )
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue like this:

step one. I declared activeKey in the component state which will decide which NavDropDown is active

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { activeKey: 1 };
 }
```

step two. The event handler function to handle onSelect event. get the event key truncate it and set it to 'activeKey' state

```
 handleSelect = (key) => {
    this.setState({ activeKey: Math.trunc(key) });
 }
```

step three. calling above function onSelect of Nav and passing 'activeKey' value to  activeKey attribute:

```
<Nav 
  activeKey={this.activeKey} 
  onSelect={this.handleSelect}> 
</Nav>
```

And it's working perfectly.